# Java Play2- Akka for jobs

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, akka, jobs

I am trying to create a job in java play2 using akka.

I always get the same error `error: cannot find symbol`

And it points to `system.actorOf()` Intellij and Eclipse don't give me an error msg.

But I can not find this method. I used the following imports

```
import play.libs.Akka;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.UntypedActorFactory;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.ActorRefFactory;
```

Maybe the docs are outdated and they have removed the `system.actorOf()` ?

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    ActorRef tickActor = system.actorOf(new Props().withCreator(new UntypedActorFactory() {
          public UntypedActor create() {
            return new UntypedActor() {
              public void onReceive(Object message) {
                if (message.equals("Log")) {
                  controllers.Application.log();
                } else {
                  unhandled(message);
                }
              }
            };
          }
        }));

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        Cancellable cancellable = system.scheduler().schedule(Duration.Zero(), Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                tickActor, "Log");

    }
}
```

EDIT:

.

oh... google redirected me to the outdated documentation. It's `Akka.System()` now..

- Can anyone give me an example on how to create the tickActor with up2date code?

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaAkka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it.

Btw there are some typos in the documentation.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader;

import static play.mvc.Results.*;
import play.libs.Akka;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.UntypedActorFactory;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.ActorRefFactory;

import akka.util.*;
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    ActorRef tickActor;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        Logger.info("D");
        tickActor = Akka.system().actorOf((new Props().withCreator(new UntypedActorFactory() {
              public UntypedActor create() {
                    return new UntypedActor() {
                      public void onReceive(Object message) {
                        if (message.equals("Log")) {
                                 //Do something
                         // controllers.Application.log();
                        } else {
                          unhandled(message);
                        }
                      }
                    };
                  }
                })));
        Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
                  Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                  Duration.create(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
                  tickActor, 
                  "Log"
                );

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you take a look at the Akka documentation about [actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/java/typed-actors.html) and [schedulers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/java/scheduler.html).

You can also take a look at this question: [Play Framework 2.0 schedules an Akka Actor at server launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177626/play-framework-2-0-schedule-an-akka-actor-at-server-launch)