# When is Akka's default system ready in Play?

Tags: akka, playframework-2.3

I was writing an application in Play 2.3.7 and when trying to create an actor (using the default `Akka.system()` of Play) inside the `beforeStart` overriden method of the `Global` object, the application crashes with some infinite recursive call of `beforeStart`, ultimately throwing an exception due to `Global` object not being initialized. If I create this actor inside the `onStart` method, then everything goes well.

My "intuition" was: *"ok, this actor must be ready before the application receives the first request, so it must be created on `beforeStart`, not in `onStart`"*.

When is `Akka.system()` ready to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Akka.system` returns an `ActorSystem` held by the `AkkaPlugin`. Therefore, if you want to use it, you must do so after the `AkkaPlugin` has been initialized.  The `AkkaPlugin` is given priority 1000, which means its started after most other internal plugins (database, evolutions, ..). The `Global` plugin has priority 10000, which means the `AkkaPlugin` is available there (and for any plugin with priority > 1000).

Note the warning in the docs about `beforeStart`:

> Called before the application starts.
>
> Resources managed by plugins, such as database connections, are likely not available at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You have to start this in `onStart()` because `beforeStart()` is called too early - way before anything like Akka (which is actually a plugin) or any database connections are created. In fact, [the documentation for `GlobalSettings` states](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/api/scala/index.html#play.api.GlobalSettings):

> Resources managed by plugins, such as database connections, are likely not available at this point.

The general guidance ([confirmed by this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177626/play-framework-2-0-schedules-an-akka-actor-at-server-launch)) is that `onStart()` is the place to create your actors. And in practice, that has worked for me as well.