# How to start an Actor only once at the Application Startup time without using Global object in Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I keep hearing the Global object will be deprecated and it is not a good practice to put some code in .onStart() of Global class. If so, what is an alternative?

Bunch of people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177626/play-framework-2-0-schedules-an-akka-actor-at-server-launch) said to use Global object however this was also 4 years ago.

I currently have the following need. I wrote an app in play that consumes messages from message queue (In my case, that is NSQ (currently there is no Camel binding to it) ) and send those messages to group of Web Socket clients that are listening to it. so I want the consumer to be initialized once for each topic and start running forever until the Application itself terminates. What happening is that when I send 10 messages to a topic I can only see 5 messages coming through but when I run the same exact method "startNSQConsumer()" from the code below in a separate Plain old Java application by itself I can see all the 10 messages. So clearly this has something to do with play and I am not sure what is going on. any ideas?

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    private static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application application) {
        EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit(() -> {
            startNSQConsumer();
        });
        super.onStart(application);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(Application application) {
        EXECUTOR_SERVICE.shutdown();
        super.onStop(application);
    }

    private void startNSQConsumer() {
        NSQLookup lookup = new DefaultNSQLookup();
        Configuration config = Play.application().configuration();
        List<String> topics = config.getStringList("TOPICS");
        String nsqlookupdIP = config.getString("NSQLOOKUPD_IP");
        int nsqlookupdPort = Integer.parseInt(config.getString("NSQLOOKUPD_PORT"));
        lookup.addLookupAddress(nsqlookupdIP, nsqlookupdPort);
        Logger.info("Using nsqlookup at " + nsqlookupdIP + ":" + nsqlookupdPort);
        topics.forEach((topic) -> {
            NSQConsumer consumer = new NSQConsumer(lookup, topic, topic + "_channel", (message) -> { // messages here will come from external system running on some other node
                String receivedMessage = new String(message.getMessage());
                //Logger.info(receivedMessage); // When I enable or disable this I only see 50% of the messages.
                EventBusManager.getEventBus().publish(new MsgEnvelope(topic, receivedMessage)); // broadcast message to all Actors listening on a particular topic
                message.finished();
            }, new NSQConfig(), new NSQErrorCallback() {
                @Override
                public void error(NSQException x) {
                    Logger.error("Cause: " + x.getCause() + ", Message: " + x.getMessage());
                }
            });
            consumer.start();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two question in one, I will answer to first, then you can refactor your code to run without `Global` and see if the issue still present. If so, then create another question.

**SCHEDULE**

In Playframework the best way to do with a scheduled task is Akka actors and Akka scheduler: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAkka.

You need to put your code (without `EXECUTOR_SERVICE`, just that part that does work) in the actor:

```
@Singleton
public class NSQRunner extends UntypedActor{    
    public static final String name = "NSQRunner";

    ...

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Throwable {
        if(msg instanceof NSQRunnerProtocol.StartConsumer){
            startNSQConsumer();
        } else {
            unhandled(msg);
        }

    }

    private void startNSQConsumer() {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can think of this actor as about a thread from the `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`. It will do the job when receiving the message that tells him to do it - `NSQRunnerProtocol.StartConsumer`. Here is the protocol class:

```
public class NSQRunnerProtocol {
    /**
     * Start the NSQ consumer.
     *
     */
    public static class StartConsumer{}
}
```

Now you need to run it on the application startup.

Here the scheduler task, that will run your actor after 1 second after startup:

```
@Singleton
public class Scheduler {

    @Inject
    public Scheduler(
            final ActorSystem system, 
            final Configuration configuration, 
            @Named(NSQRunner.name) ActorRef nsqRunner) {

        system.scheduler().scheduleOnce(
                Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                nsqRunner, 
                new NSQRunnerProtocol.StartConsumer(), 
                system.dispatcher(),
                null);        
    }
}
```

Now you need to register the actor and the scheduler in the application. Play framework has module system for this, so you need to create a module class:

```
package my.nsq

...

public class Module extends AbstractModule implements AkkaGuiceSupport {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // Bind actors.
        bindActor(NSQRunner.class, NSQRunner.name);

        // Bind scheduler, it will run on the start of application.
        bind(Scheduler.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

And register it in `conf/application.conf`:

```
play.modules {
  ...
  enabled += my.nsq.Module
}
```

**ON STOP**

In the case, if you need something to work `onStop` application then you need to inject the `ApplicationLifecycle` and a stop hook by the `addStopHook` method: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PluginsToModules#Create-a-Module-class.

Here is an example of the database access singleton:

```
@Singleton
public class Couchbase {
    private static ALogger logger = Logger.of(Couchbase.class);

    private final Cluster cluster;
    private final Bucket bucket;

    @Inject
    public Couchbase(ApplicationLifecycle lifecycle, Configuration configuration) {
        // Read the database configuration from the setting.
        final String clusterName = configuration.getString("couchbase.cluster");
        final String bucketName = configuration.getString("couchbase.bucket.name");
        final String bucketPassword = configuration.getString("couchbase.bucket.password");

        final CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment
                .builder()
                .queryEndpoints(1)
                .autoreleaseAfter(50000)
                .queryTimeout(20000)
                .retryStrategy(FailFastRetryStrategy.INSTANCE)
                .reconnectDelay(Delay.fixed(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .build();

        logger.debug(
                "Connect to the couche: cluster \"{}\", bucket: \"{}\"", 
                clusterName, 
                bucketName);

        // Connect.
        cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env, clusterName);
        bucket = cluster.openBucket(bucketName, bucketPassword);

        // Create a default index.
        bucket.bucketManager().createN1qlPrimaryIndex(true, false);

        // Special operations on the application shutdown.
        lifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {

            // Close the connection on application shutdown.
            env.shutdown();
            cluster.disconnect();

            // Couchbase close the connection synchronously 
            // so we need just return an empty CompletableFuture.
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        });        
    }

    /**
     * @return  the application bucket
     */
    public Bucket getBucket() {
        return bucket;
    }
}
```

This object you can bind in the `Module` also:

```
bind(Couchbase.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

Then you can inject it, even in your actor:

```
public class NSQRunner ...

    @Inject
    public NSQRunner(Couchbase couchbase){
        ...
    } 
}
```

You can do all your coude in the singelton like `Couchbase` it's possible, but my opinion is that actor is much better.

Comment: Vow.. Thank you so much! 1) Can I do it without DI framework? 2) Since you are scheduling once what happens when the Actor dies. will it schedule again one more time?

Comment: 1) Only if deprecated `Global` still work in your Play version. Otherwise, you will need to inject the `ApplicationLifecycle` anyway.  2) It depends on the reason of die: http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.17/akka/actor/SupervisorStrategy.html#defaultDecider

Comment: In my case, I can't think of any reason why it would (Even during a network failure the consumer shouldn't die. It should simply stop processing messages). The reason why I ask is that the consumer part is the most important for my application and if it stops my application is pretty useless so I just wanted to make sure.  Finally, I can see that you are using Guice. Is that the best DI framework to use as far as Actors is concerned? Which DI framework does most work on Actors? Any final suggestions?

Comment: Guice is default fo the Play 2.5; I do not have a problem with it.  You can specify your own strategy for the actor in the `application.conf`. I never do this, I just create some simple "parent" agent and then create a bunch of children so that I can define supervision strategy in that root actor, as well as operate with all lifecycle of child actors.

Comment: The parent for NSQRunner actor you were creating is System itself right? NSQRunner itself doesn't create/spawn child actors. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's just an example. Child creation is more complex.

Comment: Does the Module class need to have the name "Module" ? can it have any other name? Not a big deal either way but just want to know if the framework impose that requirement

Comment: Also why is InjectedActorSupport needed?  NSQRunner doesn't seem to implement any methods from  InjectedActorSupport

Comment: You ar right, that was from my code where I use child actors, so here is no need for this, I will fix my answer as well.

Comment: We are now moving to Kafka so I can finally get rid of this Global Object however my use cases remains the same which is on boot strapping the Application the kafka consumer should read messages from Kafka and send it to group of User Actors which hold Web socket connections. any suggestion and examples on how to move forward?